# AngularJs form submit issuse

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I use AngularJs to achieve submit function. When I click submit button, It does not save the form and show the data. Where am I wrong. Could you please help to check it. Thanks !

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);
  var movies = [{
    name: 'People Places Things',
    releaseDay: '14/08/2015',
    Duration: '85 mins',
    Genre: 'Comedy',
    Synopsis: 'sdfasdfasdfsadfasdfsadfasdf',
  }];
  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.products = movies;
  });
  app.controller("MovieController", function() {
    this.movie = {};
    this.addMovie = function(product) {
      product.movies.push(this.movie);
      this.movie = {};
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <h1>Moives Recommendation</h1>
    <p>
      <div>
        <table style="width: 80%">
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th id="mvTitle">{{product.name}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Release date</th>
            <th>{{product.releaseDay}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>{{product.Duration}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>{{product.Genre}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Synopsis</th>
            <th>{{product.Synopsis}}</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form name="movieForm" ng-controller="MovieController as movieCtrl" ng-submit="movieCtrl.addMovie(product)">
          <table style="width: 80%">
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>{{movieCtrl.product.name}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Release date</th>
              <th>{{movieCtrl.product.releaseDay}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Duration</th>
              <th>{{movieCtrl.product.Duration}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Genre</th>
              <th>{{movieCtrl.product.Genre}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Synopsis</th>
              <th>{{movieCtrl.product.Synopsis}}</th>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>Title:<input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.name" type="text" name="Title" /><br> Release date:<input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.releaseDay" type="text" name="ReleaseDate" /><br> Duration: <input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Duration" type="text"
            name="Duration" /><br> Genre:
          <input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Genre" type="text" name="Genre" /><br> Synopsis:
          <textarea ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Synopsis"></textarea><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I use AngularJs to achieve submit function. When I click submit button, It does not save the form and show the data. Where am I wrong. Could you please help to check it. Thanks !
I think the problem is in the addMovie function, but I can not find it.

Comment: I don't understand what `addMovie` function is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of things wrong in your code, here is working snippet

Note:Using $rootScope is not recommended but you have different controller setup in your code, thats why i tried $rootScope approach but you should use services to do this kind of Task:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);
  var movies = [{
    name: 'People Places Things',
    releaseDay: '14/08/2015',
    Duration: '85 mins',
    Genre: 'Comedy',
    Synopsis: 'sdfasdfasdfsadfasdfsadfasdf',
  }];
  app.controller('StoreController', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.products = movies;
  });
  app.controller("MovieController", function($rootScope) {
    this.product = {};
    this.addMovie = function(product) {
      $rootScope.products.push(product);
      this.product = {};
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <div >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <h1>Moives Recommendation</h1>
    
      <div  ng-repeat="product in $root.products">
        <table style="width: 80%">
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th id="mvTitle">{{product.name}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Release date</th>
            <th>{{product.releaseDay}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>{{product.Duration}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>{{product.Genre}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Synopsis</th>
            <th>{{product.Synopsis}}</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form name="movieForm" ng-controller="MovieController as movieCtrl" ng-submit="movieCtrl.addMovie(movieCtrl.product)">         
          <br>Title:<input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.name" type="text" name="Title" /><br> Release date:<input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.releaseDay" type="text" name="ReleaseDate" /><br> Duration: <input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Duration" type="text"
            name="Duration" /><br> Genre:
          <input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Genre" type="text" name="Genre" /><br> Synopsis:
          <textarea ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Synopsis"></textarea><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
   
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this. Because you are using `controllerAs` syntax so this you should put `controllerAs` variable before functions or objects.

```
  ng-submit="movieCtrl.addMovie(movieCtrl.product)"
```

**Edit:**

You have some problem in the sample. Because you are using multiple `controller` and each controller is responsible for some action. After add new product by `MovieController` you should emit it for `StoreController` to display newest product in the view. So for communication two controller you can use `$broadcast` and `$on` function. As you see in the demo.

and other problem was in displaying products. for displaying the products you should use nested `ng-repeat`.

[***Demo***](http://plnkr.co/edit/XNIp8SgjwKj7ZWCts92T?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code from yours, but It does not work. Did you try to run it.  Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In addMovie function, you should add movie to movies array only. correct function would be like:

```
this.addMovie = function(product) {
      movies.push(this.movie);
      this.movie = {};
    };
```

Other than that, you have some serious issues in your code like

1. Loading angular more than once.
2. Using form in ng-repeat itself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);
  var movies = [{
    name: 'People Places Things',
    releaseDay: '14/08/2015',
    Duration: '85 mins',
    Genre: 'Comedy',
    Synopsis: 'sdfasdfasdfsadfasdfsadfasdf',
  }];
  app.controller('StoreController', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.products = movies;
  });
  app.controller("MovieController", function($rootScope) {
    this.product = {};
    this.addMovie = function(product) {
      $rootScope.products.push(product);
      this.product = {};
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <div >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <h1>Moives Recommendation</h1>
    
      <div  ng-repeat="product in $root.products">
        <table style="width: 80%">
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th id="mvTitle">{{product.name}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Release date</th>
            <th>{{product.releaseDay}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>{{product.Duration}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>{{product.Genre}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Synopsis</th>
            <th>{{product.Synopsis}}</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form name="movieForm" ng-controller="MovieController as movieCtrl" ng-submit="movieCtrl.addMovie(movieCtrl.product)">         
          <br>Title:<input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.name" type="text" name="Title" /><br> Release date:<input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.releaseDay" type="text" name="ReleaseDate" /><br> Duration: <input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Duration" type="text"
            name="Duration" /><br> Genre:
          <input ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Genre" type="text" name="Genre" /><br> Synopsis:
          <textarea ng-model="movieCtrl.product.Synopsis"></textarea><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
   
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```